# How to restrict the control flow should not come to After method in case of any exception

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am using Cucumber with Selenium. I have a scenario, where it looks for certain objects. For that I have methods like `objectExists(WebElement)`, which in turn calls `WebDriverWait()` and I am handling it with try Catch block with `TimeOutException`. (I know findElements may solve the problem, but I wanted in case if there is any known exception which we handle, the control should not come to after method)

Here, after this `objectExists` method, I want the flow to continue with my next object verification.

But in Cucumber, the flow is coming to `@After` method.

Sample codes are:

```
    public void verifyObjectExists(WebElement element,String strObjectName)
    {
        if(verifyObjectExists(element))
            reportStatus(StepStatus.PASS,"Verify object with name '"+strObjectName+"' exists");
        else
        {
            reportStatus(StepStatus.FAIL,"Verify object with name '"+strObjectName+"' does not exists");
            embedScreenshotToCucumberReport();
        }
    }

public boolean verifyObjectExists(WebElement element)
    {
        boolean returnStatus=true;
        if(element!=null)
        {
            if(waitTillElementVisisble(driver,element))
            {
                if(element.isDisplayed())
                    returnStatus= true;
                else
                    returnStatus= false;
            }
            else
                returnStatus= false;

            return returnStatus;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }



    public boolean waitTillElementVisisble(WebDriver driver,WebElement element)
    {
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,intMaxTimeout);
        try
        {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            return true;
        }
        catch(TimeoutException e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber should not be used to describe the fine details of the scenarios. Cucumber is designed to describe the Business perspective of the features that you want to test. All the implementation details must be covered by the "glue" code that binds the both sides, the feature file descriptions and the implementation together.

Saying that, Cucumber is based on the idea that each scenario must be isolated from the others. Hence the `@Before` and `@After` hooks will run before and after each scenario respectively. If you desire to continue running the scenario despite certain errors, you must take care of that in the implementation itself rather then forcing incorrect Cucumber behavior.